# How do i restore my iPhone 5s to factory settings?

Tags: iphone, itunes, software

I have just fitted a new screen to my iPhone 5s, and i need to restore it to factory settings.

One problem though, it's disabled for over 23,000,000 minutes and the home button doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can restore it?